# Django Wagtail: Is there any option to make wagtail fieldPanel disabled?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Another question concerning Wagtail admin. I have django model for received emails. I show these models in Wagtail using **ModelAdmin**.
I would like to make this only read-only. A good solution would be possibility to disable Wagtail fieldPanels. But I can't find any info if that is possible.

Only workaround so far seems to be register custom .js file inside
ModelAdmin Class:

**my admin.py**

```
class EmailAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    model = Email       
    menu_label = "Emails"
    menu_icon = "mail"
    menu_order = 300
    add_to_settings_menu = False
    exclude_from_explorer = False
    empty_value_display = 'N/A'
    list_per_page = 10
    index_view_extra_js = ["js/wagtail.js",] # extra .js code to disable fields
    list_display = ('subject', 'name_surname', 'phone', 'email', 'text_', 'date', 'sent', 'change_seen')
```

I would like to ask you if there is some more native Wagtail way how to disable fieldPanels.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Enable `InspectView` under `class EmailAdmin(ModelAdmin)` ([reference](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/modeladmin/inspectview.html#enabling-customising-inspectview)) and then, in Groups permission assignments under Other Permissions, assign view permission to the email model.

```
inspect_view_enabled = True
inspect_view_fields = ['name', 'surname', 'email', 'text' ]
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you for reply, I know about inspection, but this solution break whole panelFields and you can see only ugly text information. That is why I don't like it, it can be ok in some cases but I would like to keep nice wagtail fileds, just disable them.

Comment: @Nikix What you're talking about is actually a styling problem, so you could just include `index_view_extra_css = ['your_app/extra_styles_admin.css']` along with the above in the modeladmin and style the fields as you would like.  You could even look at the Wagtail edit stylesheet and copy that and then disable the fields.

Comment: Thank you Dan for info, so more work but it could be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

When Defining the panels pass widget with disabled attr.

```
panels = [
    FieldPanel("surname", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"disabled": True}))
]
```